# Outputting an HTML entity character from a helper function

Tags: html, symfony1, special-characters

I am using Symfony 1.3.2 on Ubuntu. I have written a little helper function (statsfoo) that prints out summary statistics about an item.

I am using the helper function in my template like this:

```
// In StatsHelper.php
<?php
function statsfoo($some_param)
{
   return "<div class=\"sfoo\">&9830; the stats number for item is 42</div>"
}

//In  showStatsSuccess.php
<?php use_helper(Stats);
<?php echo statsfoo($foobar, ESC_ENTITIES);
```

I tried both ESC_ENTITIES and ESC_RAW. In both instances, the raw number (&9830) was displayed in the page. I want to display the diamond instead.

What am I doing wrong and how can I fix this?

Comment: `statsfoo()` is not accepting a second argument, so your `ESC_xyz` setting will never take hold, will it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
"&#9830;"
//^ remember the '#'.
```

[Numeric character references](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Numeric_character_reference) has the form of `&#123;` or `&#xABC;`, which is to different from Character entity reference `&abc;`.

(BTW, you forgot to `?>`.)

Comment: @kenny: '//^ remeber the '#'.'  D'oh!

Comment: @kenny you're not forced to close a php tag if there's not html involved after, and that will prevent having unwanted trailing spaces or CR being sent with headers